# Django, same file at the output of two different loaded files on one page

Tags: python, django

**model.py:**

```
class InJPG(models.Model):

file_path = models.FileField(upload_to="media",unique=True)
```

#in forms.py I am taking only this file_path in meta class

**views.py**

```
from model import InJPG

def get_name(request):
    if request.POST:
        file1=InJPG(request.POST or None)
        file2=InJPG(request.POST or None)
        if file1.is_valid():
            file1.save()
            print(file1)
        if file2.is_valid():
           file2.save()
           print(file2)
        return redirect(get_name)
    return render(request,'files.html',{'file1':file1,'file2':file2})
```

**files.html**

...

```
{% block page %}
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{file1}}
    
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{file2}}
        <button type="submit">upload file2</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**Situation:**

As you can see I have page where I am uploading two separate files using browse option in Django, and then to Upload them I'm using submit button, in same form in html file.

**Problem:**

I don't know why, but after submit, when I am checking which file has been uploaded, (using `print(file1) and print(file2)` ) I am receiving **ONLY** `file2`.
In models.py I have parameter `unique=True` so names are not identical but, they are coming from same file (file2)

How to solve it, and receive `file1` and `file2` in same method inside `view.py` ?

**edit:**
I've added wigets
in forms.py

```
class STH(ModelForm)
    class Meta:
      model=InJPG
      fields=['file_name']
       widgets = {
             'file_name': ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
         }
```

but without success

Comment: Does your `request.POST` have ***multiple*** uploaded files?

Comment: @Arakkal no, I dont have, should I add `widgets ` to my form.py ?